# PHP Foreach Loop Practical Application Logic

Tags: php

I just started learning PHP today and I have some conceptual questions regarding how I should use the language and accomplish specific tasks.

My question: Let's say I'm using PHP to build a CMS for a blog. On the home page I would like to have three articles show up that I have marked as "FEATURED" on the back-end in a field named is_featured.

**Here is the solution I have come up with and I would like to know if this is possible with PHP, if it's practical, or if there is a better, more efficient way:**

I would use a foreach loop to cycle through all $articles as $article and then check to see if that article has the value of FEATURED for the field is_featured.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Where are your articles stored?

Answer (score 2):

In practice the articles would (probably, hopefully) be stored in a database in a table `articles`. You'd query the database for all articles `... WHERE featured = 1 LIMIT 3 ORDER BY publishing_date DESC`, then loop through the database result set and output all found articles.

Comment: Here's my upvote to compensate for an unexplained downvote.

Comment: This makes a ton of sense and actually answers the next question I was going to have, which is how to order these articles by date. That being said, should publishing date be saved with the timestamp data type or as an int? I would assume timestamp, but I saw a tutorial where int was used instead. Does order by need a data type of timestamp or will it simply read the number inside of the field in a specific way (that is generated by php) separate from the data type?

Comment: A time should be saved as a `DATETIME`, its native database format. `TIMESTAMP` is an alternative which is mostly equivalent, unless you need dates in the far future or past.

Answer (score 0):

That would work, yes. However, this has the overhead of filling a potentially huge array with all the articles from your DB and then iterating through it to pick the featured ones.

For this kind of task, it's better to have the DB filter the results before sending them to PHP.

Answer (score 0):

In general, try to do all your filtering of data in the database, as database are specially optimized for such queries. Loading them into PHP and then filtering the records is slower and less efficient.